# Matrix multiplication issue for LU decomposition?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to solve an Ax=b by using LU decomposition, but somehow I can't get the A by multiplying L*U. Here's the code and the results;

```
A = array([2,3,5,4]).reshape(2,2)
b = array([4,3])
P,L, U = lu(A)
```

And the results for L and U

```
L:

array([[ 1. ,  0. ],

      [ 0.4,  1. ]])

U:

array([[ 5. ,  4. ],

       [ 0. ,  1.4]])
```

Result for L*U

```
dot(L,U):

array([[ 5.,  4.],

       [ 2.,  3.]])
```

So instead of ((2, 3),(5, 4)), I'm getting (( 5.,  4.),( 2.,  3.)). And as a result, I can't solve Ax=b. What is the reason for getting such L*U result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh seems like I totally forgot about the permutation matrix P. Multiplying the inverse of P with L*U solved the problem;

```
dot(inv(P),dot(P,A)):

array([[ 2.,  3.],
       [ 5.,  4.]])
```

Comment: Or you could use instead `L, U = scipy.linalg.lu(A, permute_l=True)`. Then `L.dot(U)` is as expected.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition): PA = LU.

So, if you want A = LU, you could add `permute_l=True` to `lu` function:

```
(ins)>>> a = np.array([2,3,5,4]).reshape(2,2)
(ins)>>> l,u = scipy.linalg.lu(a, permute_l=True)
(ins)>>> l.dot(u)
array([[ 2.,  3.],
       [ 5.,  4.]])
```